# Postgresql update string, add chars before and after

Tags: sql, postgresql

Help pls to update a column card_num with data like:

```
"000001"
"000002"
..
"000200"
```

**Need to do:**

```
"%000001,"
"%000002,"
..
"%000200,"
```

Comment: Check the postgresql string functions. There should be something to get the left or right chars of a field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update table set card_num = '%'||card_num||','
```

use `||` [concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) operator to leave `nulls` as `nulls`, not `%,` values